# laravel Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found

Tags: jsonserializer

Im using the following for my application for social media login
https://github.com/madewithlove/laravel-oauth2

but im getting this error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found
open: /Applications/AMPPS/www/docsearch/vendor/madewithlove/laravel-oauth2/src/OAuth2/Token/Access.php
 * @package    OAuth2
 * @category   Token
 * @author     Phil Sturgeon
 * @copyright  (c) 2011 HappyNinjas Ltd
 */

class Token_Access extends Token implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var  string  access_token
```

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.4 or higher?

Comment: And if you are using PHP version 5.4+ then you need to check if you have ````php5-json```` installed or not cause the ````JsonSerializable```` depends on that php extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't actually a Laravel issue, it's to do with your version of PHP. If you look at the official PHP documentation you'll see that this particular interface is only available for PHP versions 5.4 and up.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php